# WCF Azure long running action

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a WCF service that needs to get called so that the call will trigger a 2-3 hour of processing. I'm using windows C# client application to call the service and have set the timeouts to all the max values. When I deployed this to Windows Azure, the WCF process that was triggered by the client seems to stop after a certain moment. The client doesn't get the timeout exceptions. I can use Azure Worker Role, but the process can only be completed using only the WCF code because it is a complicated operation. In other words I can't just schedule Worker Role that executes a simple edit/insert operation to a database. So I kind of have a chicken and egg problem. The background process needs the WCF code to do the background operation, but the WCF seems to stop after a certain while on Azure. What is a way to execute a long running call in WCF and plus how to execute a long running call on Azure that needs to use the hosted cloud service WCF code to do the long running operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [the load balancer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx). The timeout used to be 60 seconds, but a few months ago this was increased to 'more than 60 seconds' (depending on the concurrent connections). Anyways, you need to keep the connection alive in order to avoid the timeout.

I suggest you try implementing this in your WCF client/service: [WCF Azure Net.TCP Keep Alive](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Azure-NetTCP-Keep-Alive-09f50fd9)

Why not rethink your architecture? Instead of depending on a connection (that can be disconnected for whatever reason), why not simply have your client drop a message in a queue? Your worker role picks up the message from the queue, does the 2-3 hour processing and once it's done it drops a message in another queue. Finally your client polls that other queue and once a message arrives there it knows the process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code required for the long running operation in a seperate project. You can then include this project in your WCF solution and your Worker Role Solution.

The background process will then have all the functionality that it requires to complete the operation.